# Difference between e and E in scientific notation

Tags: php, scientific-notation

What is the difference in PHP between a value that prints as -9.838335106976932e18 and one that prints as -9.838335106976932E+18? (note the "e18" vs "E+18")

Comment: They are the exact same number, correct?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Absolutely no difference. Those are two different conventions in printing a number in scientific notation. Specifically:

- the `E` can be either lower or upper case. The former is printed with format string `%e`, the latter (which is less common), with format string `%E`.
- the `+` before exponent (and/or base) can be omitted.

Regarding the first point, maybe those two values are printed using different format strings, but without code, it is hard to tell.