# PHP/JS scientific number notation lower/uppercase E?

Tags: javascript, php, numbers, scientific-notation

If you would run this JavaScript code:

```
console.log(1000000000000000000000);
```

You would see `1e+21`, but if you would run this PHP code:

```
echo 1000000000000000000000;
```

You would see `1E+21`, with an uppercase `E` and not a lowercase `e`, in both JavaScript and PHP both lowercase `e` and uppercase `E` are valid, but why aren't the standard the same for both languages?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Difference between e and E in scientific notation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21216316/difference-between-e-and-e-in-scientific-notation)

Comment: @YuriTkachenko That is not a possible duplicate of this question at all, since this question asks for a standard-difference between two languages, I think I wrote my question clear enough for you to understand that (especially the "in both JavaScript and PHP both lowercase e and uppercase E are valid" part), so please tell me what is unclear in that case and I might consider editing the question.

Comment: From that answer you can see that in PHP you can also see it in lower case, there is no any standard for this.

Comment: @YuriTkachenko "the E can be either lower or upper case. The former is printed with format string %e, the latter **(which is less common)**, with format string %E.", and aswell, lowercase e seems to be 100% common in JavaScript